# lstat requirements.txt: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

[image]Ive tried all solutions to this issue I could find and no luck.

My directory looks like this:

-automation

--app

---requirements.txt

--archive

--Dockerfile

How can I get the Dockerfile to recognize the requirements.txt?

```
FROM *secret*/python:3.8
            
WORKDIR /automation
            
RUN pwd
            
COPY requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
            
ADD automation automation/
RUN python3 ./app/main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem related to your work directory.
Your Dockerfile must be like taht:

```
FROM *secret*/python:3.8
            
WORKDIR /app # change this from automation to app
            
RUN pwd
            
COPY app/requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt # this line change because your requirement.txt is inside the folder app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
Copy . . # This mean copy all you files to /app     
# ADD automation automation/ # delete this line
RUN python3 ./app/app/main.py # update also this line main.py will be inside the folder app inside the working directory app
```

I hope that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Unforunately, I still get the same error:

Step 4/7 : COPY requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt
lstat requirements.txt: no such file or directory

Comment: No. Unfortunately I can not share it.

Comment: can you make ls -lrta or tree in your current directory and share a screen

Comment: Added directory layout with picture

Comment: as you can see your requirements.txt is inside the app folder this is the problem . I'll update the solution to be working in your side

Comment: Got it working with your help! Additionally, I needed to change the pip install line to "RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt" if you dont mind editing that in your solution quick. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Happy to hear that